# How to get XElement from XDocument by Line Number

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Is it possible in C# to get XElement of XDocument by giving in
the line number?

Ive got any test XML like:

```
<Student>
  <Name>Josphine</Name>
</Student>
<Student>
  <Name>Hendrick</Name>
</Student>
```

I want to give as Parameter any integer like 5.
5 would give me the Element `<Name>Hendrick</Name>`
Is this possible in any way? Or do I Need to parse the whole
XDocument by a Reader and check the line number every loop.

Comment: Why would you want to fetch by line number? What if the elements are rearranged (as is perfectly valid for XML), or whitespace is eliminated (also valid for XML)? Your stated request has a very bad code smell, you should look into XPath queries instead.

Comment: I validate a xml-file with a xsd-file.... this method gives me back the errormessage with the respective linenumber. And thats why I want to fetch the element by the linenumber. I ve built a ASP.NET MVC Programm for that. And I want to give the user the whole Content of element which is not correct.

Comment: You can't XML doesn't use new line as a separator, so  if this want all on one line it would be the same as with the line breaks

Comment: your best bet for finding the error is to just open the file and inspect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file to **string array**

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path/to/file");
```

And then get your line like `lines[4]`.

Or you should better look at **XPath** as your XML document can change.

Take a look at these exaples and tutorials: [XPath Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx), [Selecting Nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is a another look-around, if your XML is well-formed and you want your job get done using `XLinq` only, then below code might help you:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Students>
                                                  <Student>
                                                    <Name>Josphine</Name>
                                                  </Student>
                                                  <Student>
                                                    <Name>Hendrick</Name>
                                                  </Student>
                                              </Students>", LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

            IEnumerable<XElement> descendants = doc.Descendants();

            foreach (XElement ele in descendants)
            {
                string ln_num = (((IXmlLineInfo)ele).HasLineInfo() ? ((IXmlLineInfo)ele).LineNumber.ToString() : "");
                string ln_pos = (((IXmlLineInfo)ele).HasLineInfo() ? ((IXmlLineInfo)ele).LinePosition.ToString() : "");
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): at line no. {2}, position {3}", ele.Name.ToString(), ele.Value.ToString(), ln_num.ToString(), ln_pos.ToString()));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```